# Doing 4 way filter based on 3 tables using GORM

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I've been trying to achieve a 4 way to join/filter based on 4 tables "Offers", "UserPaymentMethods" and a junction table "OffersUserPaymentMethods" defined as below;

So I want to filter "offers" based on `payment_method_id` because `offer_id` lives in `offers_user_payment_methods` which makes it a bit tricky. Front-end will send `payment_method_id` and I need to filter offers based on the `payment_method_id` that's it.

```
CREATE TABLE `offers_user_payment_methods` (
  `offer_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_payment_method_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_uid` longtext NOT NULL,
  `base` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `quote` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `side` longtext NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(32,16) NOT NULL,
  `origin_amount` decimal(32,16) NOT NULL,
  `available_amount` decimal(32,16) NOT NULL,
  `min_order_amount` decimal(32,16) NOT NULL,
  `max_order_amount` decimal(32,16) NOT NULL,
  `payment_time_limit` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `state` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `user_payment_methods` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_uid` longtext NOT NULL,
  `payment_method_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_methods` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` longtext NOT NULL,
  `bank_name` longtext NOT NULL,
  `logo` longtext NOT NULL,
  `options` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will struggle to do this *efficiently and entirely with Gorm*. Preloading/associations aren't done using `join`s in Gorm and [there is no way to filter based on them](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3287). I see two potential options:

#### 1. Write your own query using `join`s and scan in the results

You can use Gorm for the query and execution, but honestly, I would just avoid all the need for reflection etc and just define a struct and scan straight into that.

The results will contain duplicated data, so you will have to manually transpose the results and build up the object.

#### 3. Execute two queries, one to find the IDs of the offers, and one to find the offers

The first query would be the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT offers_user_payment_methods.offer_id FROM offers_user_payment_methods
INNER JOIN user_payment_methods ON offers_user_payment_methods. user_payment_method_id = user_payment_methods.id
WHERE user_payment_methods.payment_method_id = ?
```

If you scan these results into `var offerIDs []int`, you can use Gorm to [find the offers by passing this slice as the param](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-objects-with-primary-key):

```golang
offers := make(Offer, 0)
db.Find(&offers, offerIDs)
```

I think this solution has the benefit of you do the *more complex* query and leave the easy stuff to Gorm (which is what it does *~ok*).